# tableView_clicked no me respeta el orden de los datos

Tags: c++, qt

```
void MainWindow::on_**tableView_clicked**(const QModelIndex &index)
{
    if(!index.isValid()){
        return;
    }
    btnEdit->setEnabled(true);
    btnDelete->setEnabled(true);
    btnSave->setEnabled(true);
    btnImg->setEnabled(true);




    QString id=mModel->data(mModel->index(index.row(),0)).toString();

    QSqlQuery q;
    q.exec("SELECT id_elemento, id_grupo, id_tipo, nombre, descripcion, icono FROM elemento WHERE id_elemento= '" + id +"';");

    qDebug()<<id;
    q.first();
    qDebug() << q.lastError();
    lineCod->setText(q.value(0).toString());
    lineGroup->setText(q.value(1).toString());
    lineType->setText(q.value(2).toString());
    lineName->setText(q.value(3).toString());
    textDescription->setPlainText(q.value(4).toString());


    lineImg->setText(q.value(5).toByteArray());



    QPixmap pixmap;
    if(!pixmap.loadFromData(q.value(5).toByteArray())){
        labelImg->setText("<b>Error de Imagen</b>");
        return;
    }
    labelImg->setScaledContents(true);
    int w = labelImg->width();
    int h = labelImg->height();

    w=200;
    h=100;

    labelImg->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Maximum, QSizePolicy::Maximum);
    labelImg->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
    labelImg->setPixmap(pixmap.scaled(w,h,Qt::KeepAspectRatio));




}




   void MainWindow::on_btnCargar_clicked()

{

    mModel=new QSqlQueryModel(this);
    mModel->setQuery("SELECT id,grupo,tipo,nombre,descripcion from vertical ORDER BY id;");


    mModel->setHeaderData(0,Qt::Horizontal,tr("ID"));
    mModel->setHeaderData(1,Qt::Horizontal,tr("GRUPO"));
    mModel->setHeaderData(2,Qt::Horizontal,tr("TIPO"));
    mModel->setHeaderData(3,Qt::Horizontal,tr("NOMBRE"));
    mModel->setHeaderData(4,Qt::Horizontal,tr("DESCRIPCIÓN"));


    tableView->setModel(mModel);

    tableView->resizeColumnsToContents();
    tableView->setSortingEnabled(true);
    proxy = new QSortFilterProxyModel(this);
    proxy->setSourceModel(mModel);
    tableView->setModel(proxy);

    tableView->show();

}
```

Funciona todo, el problema es que cuando lo ordeno por una de las columnas con el código

```
tableView->setSortingEnabled(true);
proxy = new QSortFilterProxyModel(this);
proxy->setSourceModel(mModel);
tableView->setModel(proxy);
```

el que selecciono para mostrar no corresponde  al que muestra la tabla, es decir que no tiene en cuenta el orden seleccionado anteriormente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya lo arregle, tengo que usar proxy en vez de mModel en el tableView_clicked

```
QString id=mModel->data(mModel->index(index.row(),0)).toString();
QString id=proxy->data(proxy->index(index.row(),0)).toString();
```

Comment: Añade el código (aunque sea solo la línea errónea y la correcta) y después marca la respuesta como solución